# Reducing Apache Spark Startup Time

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

I am running a **standalone** Spark cluster and submitting my applications (written in SparkR) using `spark-submit` in client mode. I have a set of applications that I have to run according to the user's input, so I can't keep them running. Each time, to submit an application and start processing data, it takes 15-20 seconds.

Can this time be reduced in any way? I have read about [having a webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090226/apache-spark-yarn-mode-startup-takes-too-long-10-secs) on the driver machine, but not sure how that can be done. Also, I am not using any cluster manager (like YARN), just a standalone cluster.

Also, do resources on the client or the cluster such as CPU cores and memory affect this startup time?

Answer (score 1):

Using a Spark job-server to share SparkContexts across applications could help you shave off start-up time. (I am not sure if you need this since your start-up time of ~20s seems quite low.)

The popular Spark job-servers which provide context-sharing are:

- [Ooyala Spark-Jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver#persistent-context-mode---faster--required-for-related-jobs)
- [Apache Livy](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/)

> Also, do resources on the client or the cluster such as CPU cores and memory affect this startup time?

Not really. The resources available should only affect the execution times of your application.

Comment: The job servers that you have mentioned do not seem to support SparkR. Are there any other servers you are aware about with R support?

Comment: Refer SparkR Example [here](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/examples/). Livy does support submitting SparkR jobs.